# Delphi - Accessing Properties from a component to an external unit

Tags: delphi, oop

I'm developing a 64 bit application in Delphi and I've divided the project into two folders. One for the components that I will use for the GUI and another for the non visual objects and the main program project.
The folders are separated, since I'd like to utilize some of the components in other projects. The Components folder is obviously in the library path.

Now I have to develop a visual component that should read some properties from a unit (called by now BaseUnit) that is in the Main folder. But BaseUnit uses some code in 64 bit asm that it's impossibile for the Components to use.
What is the best Object Oriented approach, to overcome this problem?

I'm using some simplified versions of the objects that should be read, in order for the component to be able to read the properties from BaseUnit I need. I already this in the past and it works, but I don't know if there's a more pratical way. One could be to create a base class that is compatible with both the component and the Main program, but I still don't know if the benefit is going to pay the effort of refactoring the design of BaseUnit.

I hope that I explained my issue in an understandeable way ^_^
Thank you in advance,
Paolo

**EDIT:**
Thank you all so much for the answers, the Compiler IFDEF approach is essentially the most easy way, but...
I think I'm looking for a way to let my components to exist at design time, without depending to the main project. It's a job for the main project to link them to the non-visual part of itself. 
This is because I'd like to build a GUI from a void project and just connect the properties of the components with the objects of the "engine" I'm working on (I'm developing an audio app).

All those suggestions need the Main Folder to be in the path of the Components' project. Now I'm trying to put the dummy units in the Components folder, that are copies of the BaseUnit with just the properties I need to read. In this way I can link at runtime the components to the real BaseUnit.

Comment: What do you mean by: "But BaseUnit uses some code in 64 bit asm that it's impossibile for the Components to use." ?  What error did you get?

Comment: What Paolo means is that the IDE is 32 bit and the design time package cannot have 64 bit asm.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I have no idea now what your question is really about.

Answer (score 2):

Make a good use of include files:

```
procedure BaseUnitProcThatUsesASM; assembler;
asm
  {$I asmcode.inc}
end;
```

You can put asmcode.inc in a folder specific to the platform (say i386 and x86_64) and use compiler macro for include path. I don't use Delphi actually, but I suppose Delphi has such a thing as in Free Pascal. If not, you could create 2 project files for each platform, each containing path to the specific folder.

Don't refactor what should not be refactored ;)

Comment: Yeah, this just won't work in Delphi. You'd need an IFDEF. But is doesn't sound like there is 32 bit version or even needs to be.